Show the solutions of the PDE satisfy the entropy condition
Consider the conservation law:
\begin{equation}u_t + u^3 u_x = 0, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}, \ t > 0.\end{equation}
Determine the characteristics and the solutions for the Cauchy problem $u(x, 0) = g(x)$ with both:
\begin{equation}
    (i) \; g(x) = x^\frac{1}{3},\\
    (ii) \; g(x) = -x^\frac{1}{3}.
\end{equation}
Determine the maximal domain $A$ of definition of the solutions as continuous functions: explain if they are also of class $C^1(A)$ and satisfy the entropy condition.
I'm fine in finding the solutions as well as the domains of definition for them. However, I'm a bit lost when dealing with the entropy condition: \begin{equation}u(x+a,t)−u(x,t)≤\frac{E}{t}a,\;\forall a>0,\; \forall t>0 \end{equation}where \begin{equation}E=\frac{1}{inf_\mathbb{R}A'}\in(0,\infty)\end{equation}
In particular, I don't get how I should determine $E$ (note $A(u)=u^3$ in this case) and what can I say about the entropy condition in the case $E$ is infinity or zero.

$$\begin{equation}
(i) ; u! \left(x,t\right)=\frac{\left(x \left(t+1\right)^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{t+1}\
(ii) ; u! \left(x,t\right)=\frac{\left(x \left(t-1\right)^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{t-1}\
\end{equation}$$
